# Is it a noun or a verb that follows after "go to"?

Tags: expressions

Until now, I thought the word after "go to" is a noun, like "sleep" and "work" in this example.

> He's about to go to sleep.

> I'm gonna go to work now.

Then I encountered another usage of "go to" today, which seems like using a verb after "go to."

> The companies went to cash in on the emergency.

The baffling point for me is that every dictionary seems to define "go to" as followed by a noun (e.g., [MacMillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-to_1)). Is it another informal way to use a verb after "go to?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice subtle difference you've landed on there!

The key lies not in "go" but in "to". There are different senses of "to". The first introduces a location: go to work, go to the mall, go to Canada.

The second introduces a purpose: go to deposit a cheque, go to buy milk, go to say hello.

(Note that we sometimes drop "to" in this construction, but only in the future: "I'll go buy milk" but not *"I'm going buy milk" or *"I went buy milk.")

You might find it interesting to realize that one might want to supply both a location *and* a purpose.

> He went to the store to buy milk.

> He went to the bank to deposit a cheque.

This order cannot be reversed without minor rewording.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation! :D